# How can I replace the if-else statement for something way shorter?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsstring, nsarray, simplify

I think the following code speaks for itself.

```
if (card==1) {
    cardImageString = @"myGrabbedImage1.png";
} else if (card==2) {
    cardImageString = @"myGrabbedImage2.png";
} else if (card==3) {
    cardImageString = @"myGrabbedImage3.png";
} else if (card==4) {
    cardImageString = @"myGrabbedImage4.png";
} else if (card==5) {
    cardImageString = @"myGrabbedImage5.png";
} else if (card==6) {
    cardImageString = @"myGrabbedImage6.png";
} else if (card==7) {
    cardImageString = @"myGrabbedImage7.png";
} else if (card==8) {
    cardImageString = @"myGrabbedImage8.png";
}
```

The actual if-else is 10 times bigger than this.

Card = int.

CardImageString = NSString.

'card' is only used in this statement and can be removed in your answer.

How can I simplify all this??? Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cardImageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myGrabbedImage%@.png", @(card)];
```

Comment: @vince: You want to check the card if it is between 1 and 8 just incase.

Comment: In what locale would an `NSNumber` integer have a different output? I think boxing it into an `NSNumber` and printing it out is the most flexible because whether you use `int`, `long`, `NSInteger` or anything else, it works without having to cast to avoid compiler warnings.

Comment: OK, after further testing, it turns out I'm wrong. `stringWithFormat` uses the system locale, not the current locale. So regardless of the user's locale, the code in your answer will work. I need to make a trivial edit to your answer so I can undo my vote. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I was actually trying to find a way to test this and kept thinking I was setting my locale incorrectly. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 3):

```
    cardImageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myGrabbedImage%d.png",card];
```